# i get e-mail from the data base , then i need to use href to contact this e-mail in html

Tags: php, html, database

I had table coming from the data base and there is one filed e-mail , i need to make href so when the user click can contact this e-mail .

what i did is :

```
<td><a href ="<?php echo $row->email; ?>">Contact this person</a></td>
```

When i click Contact this person outlook should open to send e-mail to this person , where the e-mail coming from data base .

But when I click, I get:

> Error loading the page.

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: SHOW US WHATS IN `$row->email` ITS RELEVANT

Comment: Are you going to do a href="mailto:me@example.com"?

Comment: what i do with points ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use mailto. Here is the code that would work

`<td><a href ="mailto:<?php echo $row->email; ?>">Contact this person</a></td>`

Answer (score 1):

To create an email link, **prefix the email address with `mailto:`**:

```
<td><a href ="mailto:<?php echo $row->email; ?>">Contact this person</a></td>
```

More info [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links).